# How to create a smart navigation with array in PHP or Javascript for previous and next?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a list of filenames

```
aeyrt.php
nviorf.php
vyutkd.php
oiuybd.php
poiuuy.php
```

Suppose that the current opened page is `vyutkd.php`

I have two arrows `<` and `>`

My question is how using PHP or Javascript the `<` will link to **nviorf.php** and the `>` to **oiuybd.php** ?

The same scenario goes if the current page is the first one. The `<` button should go to the last of the list.

Thank you

Comment: Generally you assign each one a number, and then next and previous can be determined just by simple +1/-1 maths. If you store these items in a database, the assigned number is a primary key.

Comment: @halfer thank you for this but I must avoid database for this

Answer (score 1):

You could put the files name into an array:

```
$pages= Array( 'aeyrt.php','nviorf.php','vyutkd.php','oiuybd.php','poiuuy.php');
```

And create a function that check the current file name position and return a link to the previous or next page.

```
function getLink($pages,$previous = true){
 $position = array_search(basename(__FILE__),$pages);
 if($position==0 && $previous){
  return "<a href='".$pages[count($pages)-1]."'>Previous</a>";
 }
 if($position==count($pages)-1 && !$previous){
  return "<a href='".$pages[0]."'>Next</a>";
 }
 if($previous && $position!==null && $position>0){
  return "<a href='".$pages[$position-1]."'>Previous</a>";
 }
 if($position!==null && $position<count($pages)-1){
  return "<a href='".$pages[$position+1]."'>Next</a>";
 }
}
```

I did not check if it work, but I think so ;)

**I modified the funtion to be circular**

Comment: How to call the function ?

Comment: echo getLink($pages); for previous link
echo getLink($pages,false); for next link

Comment: I also get this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting ']'

Comment: When I am on the first page, it is shown as `next` and `next` both with the same link. It is supposed to have again the previous that goes to the last link and the next to the next.

Comment: Sorry my friend but it does not working as it is supposed.... When I am in one page, the links are so messing I can not find a pattern

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65874/discussion-between-giacomo-negretti-and-xalloumokkelos).

Answer (score 0):

Would be something like this:

**corrected code:**

```
<?php
  $pages = array('aeyrt.php','nviorf.php','vyutkd.php','oiuybd.php','poiuuy.php');
  $current_file = basename(__FILE__);
  if(($current_id = array_search($current_file,$pages))){
     if($current_id == count($pages) - 1){
        echo "<a href=\"".$pages[$current_id -1]."\">previous</a>";
     }else{
        echo "<a href=\"".$pages[$current_id -1]."\">previous</a> <a href=\"".$pages[$current_id +1]."\">next</a>";
     }
  }else{
     echo "<a href=\"$pages[2]\">next</a>";
  }  
?>
```

But... I would personally put those links into database and use rewrite rules.

Comment: Thank you, however I have corrected the parenthesis on line 4 but there are other bugs in this..

Comment: When I am at the first link I get only a `next` link that goes me to the last of the list. The ideal is to still have previous and next...